# How to define date example in MicroProfile OpenAPI

Tags: java, swagger-ui, openapi, open-liberty, microprofile

I tried to create minimal example of the problem.

Let's say we have simple return object:

```
public class Result {

    @Schema(example = "2012-01-01")
    private LocalDate sampleDate;

    // omitted getter and setter
}
```

returned by simple JAX-RS endpoint:

```
@Path("/example")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Resource {

    public List<Result> example() {
        // omitted implementation
    }

}
```

MicroProfile OpenAPI in Open Liberty will automatically generate following OpenAPI (Swagger) file:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Deployed APIs
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: http://localhost:9080/api
paths:
  /example:
    get:
      operationId: example
      responses:
        default:
          description: default response
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Result'
components:
  schemas:
    Result:
      type: object
      properties:
        sampleDate:
          type: string
          format: date
          example: 2012-01-01
```

The problem is that embedded Swagger UI is displaying the date example as empty JS object:

[image: Swagger UI screenshot]

I'm not sure if this is bug on Swagger UI side because if I don't provide any example in Java annotation = any example in OpenAPI file it will render the example as current day, e.g.:

```
[
  {
    "sampleDate": "2018-11-27"
  }
]
```

Everything works correctly when I edit the OpenAPI output manually. Both single and double quotes fix the problem:

```
...
sampleDate:
  type: string
  format: date
  example: '2012-01-01'
```

or

```
...
sampleDate:
  type: string
  format: date
  example: "2012-01-01"
```

will produce expected output:

```
[
  {
    "sampleDate": "2012-01-01"
  }
]
```

Question is how to change the annotations to get desired OpenAPI output.
Single quotes are automatically escaped:

```
@Schema(example = "'2012-01-01'")
private LocalDate sampleDate;
```

will produce:

```
...
sampleDate:
  type: string
  format: date
  example: '''2012-01-01'''
```

Additional double quotes in Java doesn't have any effect on ouput:

```
@Schema(example = "\"2012-01-01\"")
private LocalDate sampleDate;
```

will produce same unquoted output:

```
...
sampleDate:
  type: string
  format: date
  example: 2012-01-01
```

I know that I can write the OpenAPI yaml output manually but that is my last resort because I don't want to sacrifice automatic generation just because date examples are not behaving as I want. Maybe some `OASFilter` can be implemented to automatically wrap date's example values or I'm just missing something obvious here.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but just FYI the UI rendering issue happens because in YAML `2012-01-01` without quotes is a [timestamp](http://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html), not a string. But in OpenAPI, `type: string` (regardless of `format`) expects a string example, e.g. `'2012-01-01'` or `"2012-01-01"`, as you already found out.

Comment: File a bug report with the tool/framework that generates the OpenAPI file, as it generate date examples incorrectly (without quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed the behaviour that you're describing.
It the issue with Swagger-UI which is packaged with Microprofile OpenAPI, you could open issue here:
[Swagger UI GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues).

The value produced, without quotes is completely valid yaml, so UI
should be able to parse it as is.

Comment: You should edit the link your post, it's broken and points to the whole repo. It would be better to link to the issue and include the quote the description

Comment: Swagger UI team doesn't consider described behavior to be a problem because there is at least two possible ways how to typecast timestamp into string in YAML format.